# Insert subquery inside INTERVAL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, intervals

This work fine:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '1:0:0' HOUR TO SECOND FROM   dual;
```

I'm trying to select some value from table and use it as INTERVAL. How can I use subquery instead of '1:0:0'?

```
SELECT INTERVAL (SELECT some_varchar_value from some_table) HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

But INTERVAL expects expression within single quotes ' '

Comment: What is the value form the table?

Comment: It can be in format 0:0:1 or 00:00:01, 9:9:9 or 99:59:59

Comment: It can be more than 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, it can be more than 24 hours, but steel it keeps in format of hours, not days

Comment: OK, updated my answer to handle that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `TO_DSINTERVAL()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions204.htm#SQLRF06133):

```
SELECT TO_DSINTERVAL(some_varchar_value)
FROM some_table;
```

But your string value needs to be in the right format. If it as shown, with just hours, minutes and seconds, you need to prepend a dummy zero for the number of days:

```
with some_table(some_varchar_value) as (
  select '1:0:0' from dual
)
SELECT TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || some_varchar_value)
FROM some_table;

TO_DSINTERV
-----------
0 1:0:0.0
```

If your hours value can be greater than 24 then you will need to split that into whole days and the remaining hours:

```
with some_table(some_varchar_value) as (
  select '1:2:3' from dual
  union all select '99:45:15' from dual
)
SELECT TO_DSINTERVAL(
    floor(to_number(regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1)) / 24)
    || ' ' || mod(to_number(regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1)), 24)
    || ':' || regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 2)
    || ':' || regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 3)
  )
FROM some_table;

TO_DSINTERV
-----------
0 1:2:3.0  
4 3:45:15.0
```

The inner part of that is splitting the original string into separate hour, minute and second components; the hour is then separate into days with `floor(hours / 24)` and the remaining hours with `mod(hours, 24)`. You can see that more clearly with:

```
with some_table(some_varchar_value) as (
  select '99:59:30' from dual
)
SELECT regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1), regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 2), regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 3)
FROM some_table;

with some_table(some_varchar_value) as (
  select '1:2:3' from dual
  union all select '99:45:15' from dual
)
SELECT regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1) as raw_hh,
  regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 2) as raw_mi,
  regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 3) as raw_ss,
  floor(to_number(regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1)) / 24) as new_dd,
  mod(to_number(regexp_substr(some_varchar_value, '[^:]+', 1, 1)), 24) as new_hh
FROM some_table;

RAW_HH   RAW_MI   RAW_SS       NEW_DD     NEW_HH
-------- -------- -------- ---------- ----------
1        2        3                 0          1
99       45       15                4          3
```